# How to implement a future with an asynchronous call back

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka

Say I have an api that returns its result asynchronously in a callback as follows:

```
def myService(callback: String => Unit)
```

And I want to wrap the implementation in a future:

```
def callService: Future[String]
```

What is the best way to connect this callback with a future returned by the callService method?

```
def callService = Future {

  myService { res: String =>
    // How to map the result to the future???
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Promise`:

```
def callService = Future {
  val p = Promise[String]
  myService { res: String =>
    p.success(res)
  }
  p.future
}
```

Disclaimer: I did not compile this code, some method names may be different, but that's the idea.

Comment: But rather than using p.complete you should probably use p.success or p.failure I guess